# Unknown file format while dealing with netcdf files from NASA (Python)

Tags: python, centos7, netcdf, netcdf4, oserror

I'm attempting to gather temperature, humidity, and pm2.5 data for a project related to heat vulnerability. I'm using the following dataset from NASA to gather temperature data: MERRA-2 inst6_3d_ana_Nv: 3d,6-Hourly,Instantaneous,Model-Level,Analysis,Analyzed Meteorological Fields V5.12.4 (M2I6NVANA) https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/M2I6NVANA_5.12.4/summary

I've downloaded the .nc4 files using curl using these instructions: https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/data-access#mac_linux_curl

I'm using the netcdf4 python library to read and understand the data, but I'm being met with this error:

```
-bash-4.2$python pyScripts/nasaData.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyScripts/nasaData.py", line 5, in <module>
    f = netCDF4.Dataset('/home/uja4bs/NASA_Data/MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Nv.20200101.nc4', 'r')
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 2353, in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__
  File "src/netCDF4/_netCDF4.pyx", line 1963, in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success
OSError: [Errno -51] NetCDF: Unknown file format: b'/home/uja4bs/NASA_Data/MERRA2_400.inst6_3d_ana_Nv.20200101.nc4'
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: are you sure the files downloaded completely and without error? it's listed as being 832 MB. Does that match the file you see? if the file you have is much smaller, try opening it with a text error - sometimes you can end up with HTML error pages instead of the actual file if something goes wrong, but it's easy to miss if you've specified the output should be called "something.nc4".

Comment: if it's a valid netCDF and you have netCDF installed, you should be able to read the file header from the command line, e.g. with `ncdump -h {filepath}`

Comment: @MichaelDelgado thank you! looks like I had a problem with the HTTP auth and I didn't catch it. It turns out the file was just the HTML pointer and was in ASCII format which was throwing everything else off.

Comment: That’s definitely caught me a bunch of times!